# Dsolve and Differential Equation for botnet defence

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I am currently using *Mathematica* to solve 
$\frac{\mathrm{d}x(t) }{\mathrm{d} t} = cv_{H} (1-x) + \beta x(1-x) - (\gamma_{min} - v_{D}(\gamma_{max} - \gamma_{min}))x$ with $ x(0) = 0$.

In the formulation, I have set $\beta = 0.21$, $c = 0.95$, $\gamma_{min} = 0.47$, $\gamma_{max} = 0.79$ so that the output is easier to read.

```
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == 0.95*v1*(1 - x[t]) + 0.21*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 
        (0.47 + v2*(0.79 - 0.47))*x[t], 
        x[0] == 0}, x, t]
```

Note: `v1` is $v_{H}$ and `v2` is $v_{D}$
This is followed by:

> DSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

and then 4 solutions to the equation. What do they all mean? Does this mean I can just pick one of these and it should satisfy everything I need?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you plot them all and see which one makes sense?

Comment: If I rationalize, don't use the initial condition and look at the general solution it sometimes gives me insight. sol = Simplify[x[t] /. Solve[x'[t] == 95/100*v1*(1-x[t]) + 21/100*x[t]*(1-x[t]) - (47/100 + v2*(79/100 - 47/100))*x[t], x[t], t][[1]]]

Comment: The output there is much nicer! I can work with the output and determine the C[1] constant by hand hopefully. Thank you.

Comment: And when you are done you can compare your C[1] with the output of Simplify[Reduce[(sol/.t->0)==0,C[1]]]

Comment: I am confused about the output that has been produced from that:
`(v1 == 0 && v2 == -(13/16)) || (C[2] $\in$ Integers && 
   9025 v1^2 + 760 v1 (17 + 8 v2) + 4 (13 + 16 v2)^2 != 0 && 
   v1 (9025 v1^2 + 760 v1 (17 + 8 v2) + 4 (13 + 16 v2)^2) != 0 && 
   C[1] == (
    2 (ArcTan[(26 + 95 v1 + 32 v2)/
        Sqrt[-9025 v1^2 - 760 v1 (17 + 8 v2) - 
         4 (13 + 16 v2)^2]] + \[Pi] C[2]))/
    Sqrt[-9025 v1^2 - 760 v1 (17 + 8 v2) - 4 (13 + 16 v2)^2])`

Comment: @AlistairLR112 To satisfy your initial condition t[0]==0 there are two possibilities, either v1==0 and (&&) v2== -13/16 or (||) the second possibility that there is some new integer constant C[2] and every one of those following equations are all simultaneously true. One of those tells you what the value of your original C[1] must be. When people try to manually solve for a constant they very often miss subtle special cases, sometimes involving complex numbers. Reduce does not miss those, but that sometimes makes the result complicated. It checks carefully to not have any zero denominators.

Comment: So any integer C[2] satisfies this, such that all those other conditions remain the same? Excellent thank you

Comment: AlistairLR112 Yes. Any C[2] such that all the other equations are true. You might compare your manual solution with the output of Reduce and if they are different then study carefully WHY they are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach is

```
int = Integrate[1/(0.95*v1*(1 - x) + 0.21*x*(1 - x) - (0.47 + v2*(0.79 - 0.47))*x), x] 
   // FullSimplify;
First@Solve[t == int - (int /. x -> 0), x] // FullSimplify
(* {x -> -0.619048 - 2.2619 v1 - 0.761905 v2 - 2.2619 Sqrt[-0.074903 - 1. v1^2 + 
 v1 (-1.43158 - 0.673684 v2) + (-0.184377 - 0.113463 v2) v2]
 Tan[0.475 t Sqrt[-0.074903 - 1. v1^2 + 
 v1 (-1.43158 - 0.673684 v2) + (-0.184377 - 0.113463 v2) v2] - 
 1. ArcTan[(1.2381 + 4.52381 v1 + 1.52381 v2)/(Sqrt[(-1.53288 - 20.4649 v1^2 + 
         v1 (-29.2971 - 13.7868 v2) + (-3.77324 - 2.322 v2) v2)])]]} *)
```

A sample plot is

```
Plot[x /. % /. {v1 -> 1, v2 -> 1}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image]